# php foreach echo prints "Array" as value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Perhaps I'm simply having trouble understanding how php handles arrays.

I'm trying to print out an array using a foreach loop.  All I can seem to get out of it is the word "Array".

```
<?php 
    $someArray[]=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'); // size 7
    foreach($someArray as $value){ 
        echo $value;    
?> 

<br />

<?php
    }
?>
```

This prints out this:

```
Array
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this would be the case.  If I define an array up front like above, it'll print "Array".  It almost seems like I have to manually define everything... which means I must be doing something wrong.

This works:

```
<?php 
    $someArray[0] = '1';
    $someArray[1] = '2';
    $someArray[2] = '3';
    $someArray[3] = '4';
    $someArray[4] = '5';
    $someArray[5] = '6';
    $someArray[6] = '7';

    for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
        echo $someArray[$i]."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Why won't the foreach work?

here's a link to see it in action >> http://phpclass.hylianux.com/test.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't declared the array properly.
You have to remove the square brackets: `[]`.

```
<?php 
$someArray=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'); // size 7
foreach($someArray as $value){ 
    echo $value;    
?>  <br />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: +1.  To be completely clear to the OP, the `[]=` operator means, essentially, "append the right-hand argument to the array which is the left-hand argument."  Thus, you've appended the array `['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']` to nothingness, resulting in `[['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']]`; an array whose first (and only) element is the array you've specified.

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  Man... I'm a victim of cross-language syntax confusion.  I'm too used to java :)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<?php 
$someArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'); // size 7
foreach($someArray as $value){ 
    echo $value . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
$someArray = array(
  0 => '1',
  'a' => '2',
  2 => '3'
);
foreach($someArray as $key => $val){
  echo "Key: $key, Value: $val<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

actually, you're adding an array into another array.

```
$someArray[]=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');
```

the right way would be

```
$someArray=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');
```