# php foreach echo prints “Array” as value

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

[php foreach echo prints "Array" as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485156/php-foreach-echo-prints-array-as-value)
asks this question but thats not the case here

```
     try {require_once'libs/config.php';
    $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table ";
  //first pass just gets the column names
  print "<table> \n";
  $result = $con->query($query);
  //return only the first row (we only need field names)
  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print "<thead> <tr> \n";
  foreach ($row as $field => $value){
   print " <th>$field</th> \n";
  } // end foreach
  print " </tr> </thead> <tbobdy> \n";
  //second query gets the data 
  $data = $con->query($query);
  $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach($data as $row){
```

> echo $row; // prints Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array

```
     print " <tr> \n";
      foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
           print "<td>$value</td>\n";       }
     } // end field loop
   print " </tr>  \n";
  } // end record loop
 // print "</tbody> </table> \n";
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } // end try
$con = null;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple that means $row is an array not an variable. You need to do `print_r($row);` instead of `echo $row;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `$value` in the `foreach` loop as it contains the values of the array elements.

Your final output will be something like this:

```
<?php
try {
    require_once 'libs/config.php';
    $con   = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table ";
    //first pass just gets the column names
    print "<table> \n";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    //return only the first row (we only need field names)
    $row    = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print "<thead> <tr> \n";
    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        print " <th>$value</th> \n";
    } // end foreach
    print " </tr> </thead> <tbobdy> \n";
    //second query gets the data 
    $data = $con->query($query);
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($data as $Somefield => $SomeValue) {
        echo $SomeValue; // prints your disered output
        print " <tr> \n";
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            print "<td>$value</td>\n";
        }
    } // end field loop
    print " </tr>  \n";
} // end record loop
// print "</tbody> </table> \n";
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
} // end try
$con = null;
?>
?>
```

Comment: you are right if you look a drop further you can see ` foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
           print "<td>$value</td>\n";       }
     } // end field loop` i'm trying to understand how arrays work so i added this echo $data to what its defined, all i get is **array**

Comment: are you looking for this? `foreach ($data as $Somefield => $SomeValue) {
        //echo $SomeValue; // prints your disered output
        print " <tr> \n";
        foreach ($SomeValue as $name => $value) {
            print "<td>$value</td>\n";
        }
    } // end field loop`

Comment: Possibly, you can handle it this way: `foreach ($data as $Somefield) {
        //echo $SomeValue; // prints your desired output
        print " <tr> \n";
        foreach ($Somefield as $name => $value) {
            print "<td>$value</td>\n";
        }
    } // end field loop`

Comment: Please add your array elements with some data so that can be easily resolved. Based on your problem that can be possible fixed with above comments and results.

Comment: in my original code i have no errors i'm just trying to learn what everything means and does i'm a newbie, my understanding is that `$data as $value` returns `$value=content`, and `data as $key=>$value` returns the `$key= column-name` and the `$value = content` i was expecting `$data as $row` should return content only

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it `foreach as ..` could not echo a full array its either key or value or both, if it's a array it prints 'array' overhere since $data contains a array the full row it just prints 'array',
which is true by every multi-dimensional array as you can see the following example from the php docs

```
    /* foreach example 4: multi-dimensional arrays */
$a = array();
$a[0][0] = "a";
$a[0][1] = "b";
$a[1][0] = "y";
$a[1][1] = "z";

foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

the result from a database is a multi-dimensional array